# signingCredentials Iusse JWT/OAuth/Identity in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I've tried to implement JWT/OAuth With Identity 2.1 in single Application MVC 5 in better words OAuth server and the resource server are the same, Since i am new to the concept i am doing as this [Tutorial](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx) has done so.
At the moment I am stuck with Getting signingCredentials going:

Here is my Code:

```
    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

        var issuer = "localhost";
        var audience = "all";
        var key = Convert.FromBase64String("UHxNtYMRYwvfpO1dS5pWLKL0M2DgOj40EbN4SoBWgfc");
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3.5);
        var expires = now.AddMinutes(_options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan.TotalMinutes);

        var signingCredentials = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(
                                    new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                                    SignatureAlgorithm,
                                    DigestAlgorithm);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, data.Identity.Claims,
                                         now, expires, signingCredentials);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

In Code above, When i Reference it as System.IdentityModel.Token i can't use it in JwtSecurityToken. When i Reference it as Microsoft.IdentityModel.Token the SigningCredentials only takes only 2 parameters, but i have to define 3 as shown in tutorial. Would you please recommend a way to solve this issue? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be using `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` which is a nuget package - for reference you can download the source code [here](https://github.com/OdeToCode/ngplaybook).